# Getting Warnings when doing Batch Build on a solution on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, speech-recognition, sphinx, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have a solution with 30 project inside.
I have rebuild the solution with the 30 projects successfully.
However, when I click on `Batch Build...` and by selecting all to build, I get 360 Warnings.

Here is a snapshot of my screen.
[image]

On the **Output** panel:

```
========== Build: 30 succeeded, 60 failed, 30 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxtrain) where I have downloaded the project.